# Dynamic point tracking with QGIS and Lizmap

Tags: qgis, lizmap

I'm working on a vehicle tracking project and would like to use QGIS and Lizmap. The data is on a PostGIS database and comes from a web service. What interests me is how to visualize the dynamics of a point. I saw that Lizmap has a custom JavaScript that refreshes the layer every x milliseconds.
Could this be the right way? I believe we need to act on levels.

Comment: What do you mean by "levels" ? Did you try the script, does it fit ? The script what it says, to refresh the layer in the current view extent.